# Can I have my application use my own implementation of a class instead of the class from a external jar

Tags: java, class, static, block

I have a situation where a external jar is loading a class which has a static block to initialise some configurations , i want to stop that happening . the only way i see is to extract that jar and remove that class file and write my own implementaion of that class. can this be done or is there any way i can stop that class from loading and load my own implementation

Comment: You can create a class with same name and package as the unwanted class in the JAR. If this class appears before the JAR in the classpath, then your class will be loaded instead of the original one.

Comment: I changed the title because it stipulated a solution to your problem, which the title now reflects.

Answer (score 0):

> JAR file is a file format based on the popular ZIP file format and is used for aggregating many files into one. A JAR file is essentially a zip file that contains an optional META-INF directory.

See: https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/specs/jar/jar.html

So it is possible to replace a class file. But I would prefer the way vanje suggested in the comment of your question.